# Return type Required for Constructor

Tags: java

I have this code here. I keep getting the error message "invalid method declaration; return type required"

```
private class HighScoresWindow extends JWindow{
   public saveWindow(JFrame parent){
       super(parent);
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A constructor should have the same name as the class, so if `saveWindow` is not intended to be a constructor, add `void` return type. `public void saveWindow(JFrame parent)`

Comment: Oh right, I am just dumb. I forget constructors need to share the name of the class. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A constructor must have the class name. If they don't share name, then there is not a constructor, is a method.

And, of course, a method needs a return type (void, int, String... or whatever else).

So, in your code, `saveWindow` method has not the same name as `HighScoresWindow` class, so the compiler is trying to read as a method without return type.

Answer (score 0):

Find correct way below:

```
private class HighScoresWindow extends JWindow{

   // constructor
   public HighScoresWindow(JFrame parent){
       super(parent);
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
   }

   // method returns nothing i.e. void
   public void myMethod(){

   }

   // method returning a String
   public String myMethod(){
       return "Hello";
   }

}
```

Comment: Constructor is a special method:
 (1) Name is same as class name (case sensitive)
 (2) Without any return type

Answer (score 0):

constructor should have the same name as the class. "saveWindow" is not a constructor and is a method

Answer (score -1):

your method is not returning anything. i.e. no return.
If that is what you are intending then add `void` to your method declaration

Comment: `public saveWindow void`?? Surely that must be a typo

Comment: Yeah I'm guessing that's a typo, but I am just dumb. I forgot constructors had to share the name of the class. Thanks!